# c# How to show the total of values in a column in a listview?

Tags: c#, listview, addition

I have to make a listview in WindowsForms, in which certain values must be added together, but I have no idea how to make this. Please can somebody help.

Comment: WindowsForms, WPF or ASP.Net? It's also useful to add the code that you have tried so far as this lets people know where you are at and what may/may not be useful to suggest.

Comment: oh! sorry - it`s a WindowsForms Application

Comment: When you say certain values, do you mean all the values in a certain column, or only some of those values in that column, or something else? You can iterate through a column in a `ListView`  by iterating over `ListView.Items`, then checking the column, by index, via `item.SubItems(3).Text`

Comment: i mean all the values in a certain column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Mario to get your values in 1 column try this...i used a simple list
this will put values in first column

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            lst.AddRange(new string[]{"one","two","three","four"});
            foreach(var value in lst)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(value);
            }
```

if you want to put it in any other column try this

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            lst.AddRange(new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" });
            int column = 1 ;//this could be some input like int.Parse(TextBox1.text)
            int row = 0;
            foreach (var value in lst)
            {
                if (!(column >= listView1.Columns.Count))//check to see if its not above column collection
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
                    lvsi.Text = value.ToString();
                    listView1.Items[row].SubItems.Insert(column, lvsi);
                    row++;
                }

            }
```

ok Mario then you need this i think

```
private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                value += int.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[e.Column].Text);
            }

            textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
        }
```

its the eventhandler for the columnclick event of listview,so when you
click the columnheader it will fire this logic....good coding

Comment: Thanks, but i mean when I have a column with values e.g. 10, 20 and 30 Then I need a textbox, in which the total of these values is shown.