# Sum ListView specific column

Tags: c#, listview

i'm looking solution for this case, i got a listview and i have to show a simple cashier.

[Appearence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muUAg.png)

And my doubt is why can i show the sum of the all items in my listview in my bottom **textBoxTotal**

```
codProduto = int.Parse(txtCodProd.Text);
nomePRod = txtNomeProd.Text;
quantidade = int.Parse(txtQuantidade.Text);
valorUnitario = nvo.procurarPreco(int.Parse(txtCodProd.Text));
valorTotal = quantidade * valorUnitario;

valorAcumulado += valorTotal;

  0   1      2             3             4      <<number columns
//ID NOME QUANTIDADE VALOR_UNITARIO VALOR_TOTAL

ListViewItem itens = new ListViewItem(codProduto.ToString());
itens.SubItems.Add(nomePRod.ToString());
itens.SubItems.Add(quantidade.ToString());
itens.SubItems.Add(valorUnitario.ToString());
itens.SubItems.Add(valorTotal.ToString());

listView.Items.Add(itens);
```

When i tried to create a loop to catch colum with values that i need, i fail.

something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
//{
//    valorAcumulado += decimal.Parse(listView.items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
//}
```

I just need the 4 column sum and show it... even if new item is added.

Comment: What error you getting ? sum = 0  or exception ?

Comment: Kindly see this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004522/c-sharp-how-to-show-the-total-of-values-in-a-column-in-a-listview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a `GridView` is better for your case than a `ListView`.

The loop you wrote just have a typo, it's `Items` and not `items` for `ListView` :

```
decimal valorAcumulado = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
{
    valorAcumulado += decimal.Parse(listView.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
}
Console.WriteLine(valorAcumulado); // 83
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double valorSum = 0;

foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView.Items) // listView has ListViewItem objects
{
   valorSum += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[4].Text); // Columns 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objects don't look well-formed.  Try to re-organize it so it will be easier to follow and maintain.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<CartItem> cartItems = new List<CartItem>();
            cartItems.Add(new CartItem
            {
                ItemNumber = "1234",
                Description = "Small widget",
                Quantity = 2,
                Price = 1.50,         
            });

            cartItems.Add(new CartItem
            {
                ItemNumber = "6789",
                Description = "Large widget",
                Quantity = 1,
                Price = 10.00,
            });

            double total = 0;
            foreach(CartItem item in cartItems)
            {
                total += item.ExtendedPrice;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Your total is $" + total.ToString());

        }
    }

    public class CartItem
    {
        public CartItem(){}

        public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double ExtendedPrice { get { return Price * Quantity; } }
    }   
}
```